# Miss join da in left join when data quantity increase in Hive

Tags: join, hive, mapreduce

In this hive sql, when the quantity of data in table1 is big, t2.c will lost but it should be joined, how to exlpain this in the level of mapreduce?

```
SELECT
  t1.a,
  t1.b,
  t2.c
FROM
  table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
  ( 
    select
        t02.id,
        t02.c
    from 
        (
            SELECT
                id,
                c,
                row_number() over (partition by id order by c) rk
            FROM
                table2
        )t02
    where t02.rk = 1 
  ) t2
ON
  t1.id = t2.id;
```

May be the maptasks take too much time

Comment: It is not clear what exactly the problem. Please provide some example

Comment: Are you looking for SQL advice or python?  Please clarify what you are asking for please.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calculating row numbers and then dispensing with most of them, try just grouping and retuning the minimum value of c instead.

```
SELECT
      t1.a
    , t1.b
    , t2.c
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
          t02.id
        , t02.c
    FROM (
        SELECT
              id
            , MIN(c) as c
        FROM table2
        GROUP BY
              id
        ) t02
    ) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

Also note that you have elected to use a LEFT JOIN so if there are table1.id values that are not present in table2, then the column c will be NULL. You could use an INNER JOIN instead to suppress any rows in the result that have no match between the two tables.